# Mill's methods - logic

Tags: logic, induction, john-stuart-mill

Which Mill's method (not considering their limitations) would you use if you need to rule out the identity of a murderer based on the murders he already committed?

The only possible answers are method of agreement or method of difference.
We are having a huge debate, some people are sure that it would be the method of agreement, others the method of difference. Each are giving reasonable explanations...but it really depends on how you build the tables. What happened if you have 3 murderers with the same characteristics? We need more opinions.

As I mentioned, the question is:

> Rule out hypotheses about the identity of a serial killer based on the characteristics of each of the murders that he has already carried out. This is an example of causal inference following the method:

> A) agreement

> B) difference

I see it as difference to be able to rule out the identities...but I need to see it from different points of view. Feel free to share yours.

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

*Long comment*

In order to use so-called [Mill's Methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mill%27s_Methods), IMO the issue is how to "model" the problem.

Assume that we have a certain set of known murders, meaning that we know the respective murderer.

We may symbolize them with:

A occurs together with a b

B occurs together with c d

C occurs together with e f.

And we have a unknown murder: X occurs together with y z.

The assumption is that the unknown murderer X must be one of A,B,C.

We may summarize the three known murder in one single line of the table:

A B C occur together with a b c d e f

that added to the line:

X occurs together with y z

will be the description of the problem.

Now, according to the **Direct method of agreement** we have to match the characteristics y,z with the list a,b,c,d,e,f.

The match (if any) will produce the result X=?

Comment: Thank you so much!

This was a question asked by university professors without any additional details...so it created several types of possible inferences. At the end they said that it was the method of agreement but without giving further reasoning. I still see how both are possible.

Do you think it would be possible to solve it with the method of difference as well?

Have a nice day!

Comment: @Ethinker - you are welcome... Regarding the difference, you have to try to model the problem.

Comment: My doubt was because they shared the solution based on this (and I think cannot be because it will be a paradox):
It is clear that the murders already carried out by him are going to be evaluated, the  effect is present for all occurrences. The method of agreement is the only one that allows making causal inferences based exclusively on the analysis of the cases in which the effect is always present. 
BUT...If the effect is the characteristics of the murders he has already committed (P), we can never rule out the murderer. It will always be present because it is the necessary cause (P).